# Grant para varias tabelas Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou precisando criar um usuário do banco de dados, onde ele poderá ter permissão de todos os DML, porem ao criar o grant tenho que especificar tabela por tabela, existe alguma forma de dar permissão para todo o banco, segue o meu exemplo:

```
GRANT select, update, delete, insert ON BANCO01.TABELA01 TO STACKOVERFLOW
```

Porém, como eu disse, estou tendo que setar tabela por tabela!

Answer (score 1):

Eu gosto de gerar os scripts de `grant` na mão, pois geralmente executamos uma vez, através de uma `query`:

```
SELECT 'GRANT select,update,delete,insert ON ' || x.table_name || ' TO STACKOVERFLOW;'
  FROM all_tables x
 WHERE x.owner = USER;
```

Então o resultado eu copio e executo.

---

Ou o mesmo caso usando [BULK COLLECT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html), quando temos um grande volume de tabelas:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
  TYPE t_string_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  vcursor      t_cursor;
  varraystring t_string_array;
  i            BINARY_INTEGER;

BEGIN
  OPEN vcursor FOR
    SELECT 'GRANT select,update,delete,insert ' || x.table_name || ' TO STACKOVERFLOW'
      FROM all_tables x
     WHERE x.owner = USER;

  LOOP
    FETCH vcursor BULK COLLECT
      INTO varraystring;
    EXIT WHEN varraystring.count = 0;
    FOR i IN varraystring.first .. varraystring.last LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varraystring(i);
    END LOOP;
    EXIT WHEN vcursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE vcursor;

END;
```

Existem outras formas mais complexas de fazer, mas acredito que essa resolva seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Pode também utilizar o EXECUTE em um loop. Ex:

```
FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM all_tables)
LOOP   
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT select,update,delete,insert ON ' || x.table_name || ' TO STACKOVERFLOW'; 
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Desculpa a pergunta, mas quando eu executo o código acima, mudando para os meus reais parâmetros, esta dando erro de sintaxe, preciso me atentar a alguma condicional ?

Comment: Talvez precise do `BEGIN` e `END;` respectivamente no início e no final, caso o script não seja reconhecido. Se funcionar eu atualizo a resposta :)